# Is this a correct universal __repr__ definition?

Tags: python

For a long time I have been puzzled by Alex Martelli's [remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr/1436756#1436756) about:

> (...) the fuzzy unattainable goal of making **repr**'s returned value
>   acceptable as input to **eval**!

So I gave it a try and came up with this:

```
class Sic():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.method_var = lambda x, y, z : x + y + z

    def __repr__(self):
         def right_quotes(value):
             return  repr(value).translate(str.maketrans('\'\"', '\"\''))
         from inspect import signature
         class_sig = signature(self.__class__)    
         fields = tuple('{}={}'.format(k,right_quotes(v)) for k,v  in self.__dict__.items() if k in class_sig.parameters)
         return self.__class__.__name__ + str(tuple(sorted(fields))).replace("\'","")
```

Is this a correct general implementation of `__repr__`? If not could you give an example where it fails?

(I have improved the original version with the suggestion of Barmar, and responding to the objection of Kuco 23. I am looking here to a most general solution, even if it involves using introspection.)

Comment: It should probably be `.format(k, repr(v))`.

Comment: What if one of the values is a resource like a file object, e.g. `Foo(open('bar'))`? That can't be represented in a transportable way.

Comment: @Barmar nice suggestion, added.

Comment: @deceze In that situation it will not work. Agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the quote means is that, when a string returned from the `__repr__` method is ran on a python interpreter, it should evaluate to the object at its initialization stage.

The code you provided has a couple of faults.
Any object encoded in the `__repr__` return string, should also be represented with their `__repr__` method.
And also the `self.__dict__.items()` will return (name, value) pair for every attribute name set to the object self. The problem here is that some of those object were not used for the self's initialization. For example if your code was modified as

```py
class Sic():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.method_var = someFunction(x, y, z)

    def __repr__(self):
         fields = tuple("{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in self.__dict__.items())
         return self.__class__.__name__ + str(tuple(sorted(fields))).replace("\'","")
```

the repr method would return `Sic(x=x0, y=y0, z=z0, method_var=mv0)`, even though that string's evaluation would be invalid, as the `__init__` method only takes 3 arguments.

The safest option would be to implement the `__repr__` method for any class you implement separately, as in

```py
class Sic():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __repr__(self):
         args = map(repr, (self.x, self.y, self.z))
         return f"Sic({', '.join(args)})"
```

If you insist on defining a `__repr__` method for a custom class, you would have to know for each object, which arguments the `__init__` method takes in, which would probably require some additional modifications to every class and make the code more complex.

Comment: Your objection is really valuable, but see my correction in the original question.